# Start-up Performance Issues with Entity Framework, SQL Server CE 4.0 and Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, database-performance, ef-power-tools

I am using Entity Framework (EF) 5.0, Code First approach, and SQL Server CE 4.0 database in my application. However, I am facing a major performance problem on application start-up.

I searched on the Internet and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853) article which explains which operations affect start-up performance, and one of them is view generation. So, I looked into how I could generate views at compile time and link them to EF at run-time instead of creating views at run-time. I came across Entity Framework Power Tools which provides a command to generate views through your DbContext class.

I have generated the views at compile time using Entity Framework Power Tools as described in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/09/ef-power-tools-beta-2-available.aspx#10374587) article. However, when I run my application with SQL Server CE it always generates the following exception:

> *The mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer 'DatabaseContext' no longer matches the information used to create the pre-generated views.*

whereas the same application works fine with SQL Server database. So, I searched more but  have not found a fix to this problem. Following are links where people have reported similar performance problems:

1. [MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx)
2. [Entity Framework forum on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2665d359-188f-4e2c-a13b-4718754616f0)

My question is this: "Is there a workaround or solution for this application start-up performance problem?". I need to use SQL Server CE and not SQL server.

Comment: You need to pre=generate views each time you change the model.

Comment: That's what I am doing Pawel and the issue is that when I generate the views after updating the model, then on the very first run it raises the exception that views are out of date, but when I do the same with SQL Server it works fine.

Comment: Is it the same machine or you run it on a different box?

Comment: @Powel, I investigated more on this issue and found that when I use the Power Tools command "View Entity Data Model XML", then the XML generated by the tool is a little different than what is generated at run time using EdmxWriter.

Comment: Following are the statements which are different:
At compile time:
<Schema Namespace="CodeFirstDatabaseSchema" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005" Alias="Self" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">

At run time:
<Schema Namespace="CodeFirstDatabaseSchema" Provider="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" ProviderManifestToken="4.0" Alias="Self" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">

Comment: I guess that is why I was able to run the application with SQL Server database without any exception. If, I am right, then could you please let me know how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I agree that the issue is that you have different Provider since this results in talking to different providers what in turn means that you have different store types and in general your store model is different. The question is why you have two different providers? Are you changing connection strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually EF Power tools were generating the view using the default provider **SqlClient** but, I needed to generate the views for **SqlServerCe.4.0** provider which, I was unable to figure out why every time generated views goes out of date and finally I figured out why it was not working.

So, I just commented the DbContext constructors from my context class and, then I ran the "Generate Views" and "View Entity Data Model XML" command of EF power Tools, then EF Power Tools took the connection string from **App.config** otherwise it uses a default connection string that connects to Sql Server with SqlClient as provider.

So, I believe that if anybody uses any other provider like Devart's Oracle provider etc., then he/she needs to generate the views by specifying the connection string and provider information in App.config (for desktop applications) or web.config (for web applications) and comment out the DbContext constructors (or hide it from EF Power Tools using per-processor).